# What type of substitution to use?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I am trying to solve the following Sturm-Liouville problem.
$$(\frac{1}{x^{2m}}\cdot{y'})'+\frac{m(m+1)}{x^{2(m+1)}}\cdot{y}+\lambda\frac{1}{x^{2m}}\cdot{y}=0$$
Re-written as :
$$y''-\bigg(\frac{2m}{x}\bigg)y'+\bigg(\frac{m(m+1)}{x^2}+\lambda\bigg)y=0$$.

What type of substitution should be used to solve this ODE?
It is cannot be an euler , and cannot figure out how to use a different method.

Comment: Yes, could you please elaborate how that would help?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the ODE

Comment: You can try Series solution maybe. Yisroel

Comment: Try $y(x)=w(x^{2m+1}/(2m+1))$ and see if the equation for $w$ is better for what you want.